# Cleaning Projects and Servers to see my changes working

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Let me explain..

I used to program all day just cleaning projects(Project > Clean) and JBoss server(Right click on it > Clean) sometimes.

Something around 10 times in a day of 8 hours working.

Now I need to do it all the time, otherwise it won't get my code updated.

Is there something that I can do to avoid doing it all the time?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Run your server in debug mode, so that it has [hot-swap](http://www.jug.mk/blogs/ipenov/entry/hotswapping_using_jvm) enabled. Then make sure you send each changed file to the server. This can be done either via WebToolsPlatform or using the FileSync plugin. If using ant, [this looks interesting](https://hotswap.dev.java.net/)

A paid option to increase creativity is [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). I haven't used it, and the advice I pointed out above are sufficient for me, but take a look at it as well.

Btw, avoid doing clean that often. It is a slow process.

Comment: I'll check as soon as I can. I already run my server in debug mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ant' script to clean and build and link it with Eclipse as Builder.

First create a ant script with a target which will do the clean build.

Now go to Eclipse and right click the project and select 'Properties' and select 'Builders'. Click 'Add' button and select 'Ant Builder'. In the shown dialog , point to the ant file you created. Select 'Targets' and select the targets which you want to run.